# Python3, how to keep escape sequcence (b'\x41' ), when the case it can be represented in ascii(eg: b'A') in bytes ?

Tags: python, byte, ascii, literals

Although I know they are equavilent:

```
>>> 'A'.encode() == b'\x41'
True
>>> b'\x41' == b'A'
True
```

But when:

```
>>> 'A'.encode()
b'A'
```

From pydoc, this is the default behavior when bytes escape sequence \xXX if XX's decimal value < 127, it will be represented by its ascii according to chr().

I want something:

```
>>> 'A'.encode()
b'\x41'
```

Is there any way to do this?

Currently I'm using memoryview(b'A').hex() and binascii.hexlify(b'A') to help to get the true hex value of b'A' .

Comment: What do you want as an actual result?

Comment: Also, there's an easier way to see the hex-values: `list(map(hex, my_bytes_object))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just some debug use, it's very annoying when compare some value temporary using print, but you see the actual hex values become ascii instead. Thank you for your response.